# SoapUI teststep or groovy can't consume big messages from Weblogic JMS queues through hermes

Tags: groovy, weblogic, soapui, hermes-jms, jms-queue

I have a testCase that has a mockresponse test step and the endpoint is reading from a weblogic jms queue jms://WLS::-::queue_SouthboundOutboundQueue .

When the message from weblogic reaches '10000000' bytes this test step stops consuming the message in the running of the testcase.

Tried reading the queue from a groovy script like this :

```
def jmsEndPoint = new JMSEndpoint("jms://WLS::-::queue_SouthboundOutboundQueue");
log.debug(jmsEndPoint.sessionName);
def hermes = HermesUtils.getHermes(context.testCase.testSuite.project, jmsEndPoint.sessionName);
def jmsConnectionHolder = new JMSConnectionHolder(jmsEndPoint,hermes,false,null,null,null);
Session session = jmsConnectionHolder.getSession();
Queue queue = jmsConnectionHolder.getQueue(jmsConnectionHolder.getJmsEndpoint().getReceive());
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
Message message = null;
def count = 0;
while((message = consumer.receiveNoWait()) != null){
    //error happens here when it is consumed
    count++;
}
```

Error thrown by groovy when reading big messages

[image]

> weblogic.jms.common.JMSException:
>   weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherException:
>   weblogic.rjvm.PeerGoneException: ; nested exception is:
>   weblogic.socket.MaxMessageSizeExceededException: Incoming message of
>   size: '10000080' bytes exceeds the configured maximum of: '10000000'
>   bytes for protocol: 't3' error at line: 22

PS: Weblogic is working with big messages because I added the -Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize=2000000000 to it. Also tried adding this parameter on soapui and hermes sh and bat starter files but nothing worked.

Comment: what OS do you have? could you provide the changes in `bat` and/or `sh` you did to add `-Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize=..`. could you check in groovy step the result of  `System.getProperty('weblogic.MaxMessageSize')`

Comment: My OS is Win10. In the groovy added this lines to test: def d = System.getProperty('weblogic.MaxMessageSize'); log.info d; Result seems correct: ...INFO:2000000000 In soapui.bat loadtestrunner.bat wargenerator.bat mockservicerunner.bat securitytestrunner.bat testrunner.bat toolrunner.bat added the paramenter to set JAVA_OPTS in all: set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128m.. -Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize=2000000000 In SoapUI-5.3.0.vmoptions added in the end -Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize=2000000000 In hermes.bat and hermes-14.bat added the param to 'start "HermesJMS"..' line. In hermes.sh added to '"$JAVACMD"' line